# error in js file: 'body' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery_and_timers.js. But when i try to run my webpage. It gives following error:
Line: 16
Error: 'body' is null or not an object

Here is the error line:

```
return Math.max(f.documentElement["client" + c], f.body["scroll" + c], f.documentElement["scroll" + c], f.body["offset" + c], f.documentElement["offset" + c])
```

Can anyone tell how to fix this?

** I think this is where it is happening: 
I call a method

```
loadIframe() from $(document).ready(function () {... 

function loadIFrame() {
        $("#toggleStyle").attr("href", "style/la.css");
        $('#Src').insertBefore('#togg');
        $("#inf").attr("src", "images/inf.png");        

}
```

It is when this method loadIframe is called it gives that error.

Comment: What is `f` in this context ?

Comment: When is it being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really not enough code in your question, but since the error is about `body`, and not about `documentElement`, I'm guessing `f` is `document`, and you're running the code before the DOM is ready.

You can run the code after the DOM is ready by placing it in a handler passed to jQuery's `.ready()` method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // your code

});
```

---

Or if in spite of the jQuery tag you're not using jQuery, just place your script just before the closing `</body>` tag...

```
<body>

    <!-- your HTML -->

    <script>
        // your script
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this code being called in the `<head>` of your document? If so, the body doesn't exist yet.